# Can I use an Facebook Administrator role/account to test Facebook app as an equivalent to Facebook Developer role/account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

From https://developers.facebook.com/apps/, I want to upgrade the Facebook API version from v2.8 to v3.2. However, I want to "Upgrade Calls for App Roles" (change the API version your app calls for developers) first before I "Upgrade All Calls" (change the API version your app calls for all users):

[image]

When I go to the Roles section, I see the administrators and developers assigned to my app in boxes like this:

[image]

I want to use an Administrator Facebook account to test the app making requests to the Facebook API v3.2. However, I do not know if for this purpose, an Administrator account is the equivalent of a Developer account. That is my question: Can I use an Facebook Administrator role/account to test Facebook app as an equivalent to Facebook Developer role/account? Thank you.

Comment: Both are “app roles”, so when you upgrade API calls for app roles, that will affect app admins and app developers both.

Comment: Cool. That was what I needed to know. Please write this as an answer to this question so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Admin and Developer are app roles, so when you upgrade API calls for app roles, that will affect both. And Testers as well, the third app role.

The difference Admin vs Developer is mostly regarding what app settings they are allowed to change, other than that, there is very little difference between them.